# How to write it using streams? Java 8

Tags: java, foreach, filter, java-8, java-stream

I wrote a piece of code and wonder how I can write it more elegant, using streams
here it is:

```
public boolean possibleToAddTask(LocalDate taskDate, final String username) {
        List<Task> userTasklist = find(username).getTaskList();
        for(Task task : userTasklist) {
            if(task.getDate().equals(taskDate)){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Here - some boolean is returned from a method. If specified date already exists in some task it returns **false**, otherwise **true** (so the return type answers the question raised in method's name :))

I was trying with filters on streams, but It worked just for a while, and then unit tests gave me some unexpected results so I deleted it and wrote it like Its upper. Now I want to beautify it

previously it was like this:

```
public boolean possibleToAddTask(LocalDate taskDate, final String username) {
        List<Task> userTasklist = find(username).getTaskList();

        try {
            userTasklist.stream().filter(n -> n.getDate().equals(taskDate)).findFirst().get();
            return true;
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Method findFirst() return an Optional. So you can just check if optional is empty.

```
return !userTasklist.stream()
.filter(n -> n.getDate().equals(taskDate))
.findFirst().isPresent();
```

Or even easier approach.

```
return !userTasklist.stream().anyMatch(n -> n.getDate().equals(taskDate));
```

**EDIT**: Now unit tests should pass.

Comment: Hmm... Maybe this is a bit better since it mimics the original logic more closely.

Comment: @lusiak Seems to be perfect solution, however unit test still returns OK for no-stream-solutions, and FAILS for streams-solutions

Comment: I probably know why. Just negate what stream return.

Comment: yup I found it out a minute ago, had to think it over :) its the right solution, thanks! still so many things about streams to learn..

Answer (score 0):

How about doing something lik transforming the List into Set and then calling contains():

```
return userTasklist.stream().map(Task::getDate).collect(Collectors.toSet()).contains(taskDate);
```